# How does the power log entry in HTC Nexus One G5 or amazon Kindle Fire differ?

Tags: android, nexus-one, kindle-fire

The 'power' logcat entry in the HTC Nexus One G5 And Kindle fire seem to be different from other devices.

In my smartphone (HTC G7 Desire and Motorola Xoom),the log as follows:

> 11-24 09:24:36.748: INFO/power(13223): *** set_screen_state 0
>
> 11-24 09:24:38.430: INFO/power(13223): *** set_screen_state 1

But in HTC Nexus One G5 and amazon Kindle Fire , the log is different. Does anyone know how it appears in these devices?

Comment: I edited this to be an actual question, instead of a request for someone to just paste their log.

Answer (score 0):

On kindle Fire HD I get

```
11-23 15:15:16.881: I/power(207): *** set_screen_state 0
11-23 15:55:24.471: I/power(207): *** set_screen_state 1
```

this is an ICS based device. Were you seeing something different on the original (Gingerbread based) Fire?